# Trabajar con un arraylist en varias clases

Tags: poo, arraylist

Alguien sabe si se puede trebajar con un solo ArrayList en varias clases, y si no es así, que otro método se puede hacer para para la información de un ArrayList a otro. El ArrayList es de tipo Objeto

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon un ejemplo que ilustre el problema específico. Tal y como está la pregunta es bastante confusa y no queda claro lo que quieres. ¿Puedo trabajar con un `ArrayList` en varias clases? ¿Por qué no?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.